# Displaying upload progress

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, codeigniter

i use CodeIgniter 2.0 framework and i would like when i upload a picture to see a progress bar or even just a percentage. I dont care if its strait php or Javascript or jquery as long as it works!

i would like example code or a link to a good tutorial if possible.

Comment: @motionman95, using URL shorteners to evade the ban on LMGTFY links is not tolerated.

Comment: :O There's a ban on LMGTFY links?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you checked out Uploadify:
http://www.uploadify.com/

You can integrate this quite nicely with CodeIgniter to provide exactly what you're looking for as well as multiple uploads etc.

As far as I know the only way to easily show percentage of uploads is to use a flash file of some kind to deal with the upload process. This is what Uploadify does.

Comment: thank you i had seen references to this on the net but all the links were dead except the one you gave me that i never found before